# Screwed up my disk messing with diskutil. Can't re-partition

Tags: disk-utility, monterey, apple-silicon

I was messing with diskutil and ended up "configuring" my disk to where it will not repartition properly. When I attempt, it tells me disk0 is being used by kernel process 0.

I am wondering if I need to reinstall macOS using a USB image or if I am just a couple of commands away from fixing my issue here. If additional information is needed please let me know!

I do not care about any data on the disk itself.

[image]

I am going to rewrite a post with much more detail into the methods that I have tried.

Comment: Do you have a backup (time machine or other)?

Comment: No, I do not. I am not worried about any information on the drive itself. Just want to get it in shape for repartitioning. But I can't seem to do that with disk0 being occupied by process 0.

Comment: What is the output of `mount`?

Comment: @pion
/dev/disk4s1 on / (apfs, sealed, local, read-only, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /System/Volumes/xarts (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /System/Volumes/iSCPreboot (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s3 on /System/Volumes/Hardware (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
tmpfs on /System/Volumes/Data (tmpfs, local)
tmpfs on /Volumes (tmpfs, local)
/dev/disk2s1 on /System/Volumes/Data/private/tmp/Recovery (apfs, local, read-only, journaled, nobrowse)
tmpfs on /System/Volumes/Preboot (tmpfs, local)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out why process '0' wouldn't allow me to erase/unmount my disk. However, in order to fix my botched disk, I had to plug my Mac into another Mac with Apple Configurator installed.

Doing this I was able to successfully wipe my own disk without any issues.